# Which parser generator would be useful for manipulating the productions themselves?

Tags: parsing, parser-generator

Similar to [Generating n statements from context-free grammars](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2840624/generating-n-statements-from-context-free-grammars), I want to randomly generate sentences from a grammar.

What is a good parser generator for manipulating the *actual* grammar productions themselves?  I want the parser generator to actually give me access to the productions (production objects?).

If I had a grammar akin to:

```
start_symbol ::= foo
foo ::= bar | baz
```

What is a good parser generator for:

- giving me the starting production symbol
- allow me to choose one production from RHS of the start symbol ( `foo` in this case)
- give me the production options for `foo`

Clearly every parser has internal representations for productions and methods of associating the production with its RHS, but which parser would be easy to manipulate these internals?

Note: the blog [entry](http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2010/01/28/generating-random-sentences-from-a-context-free-grammar/) linked to from the other SO question I mentioned has some sort of custom CFG parser.  I want to use an *actual* grammar for a real parser, not generate my own grammar parser.

Comment: Be careful with automatic phrase generation: http://thedailywtf.com/Articles/The-Automated-Curse-Generator.aspx

Comment: It's probably much easier to roll your own than rely on the internals of a parser generator. The only hard part is writing a parser for the grammar files.

Comment: @larsmans , I think that would be a nightmare which is why I wrote this question.  I want the grammar to double as an actual grammar to an actual parser (not for parsing language, for parsing hardware transactions).  So the grammar itself will have embedded code, which I'd have to skip.  If someone has some clean internals, I'd rather not recreate a grammar parser.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should be pretty easy to write a grammar, that matches the grammar that a parser generator accepts. (With an open source parser genrator, you ought to be able to fetch such a grammar from the parser generator source code; they all then to have self-grammars).   With that, you can then parse any grammar the parser generator accepts.

If you want to *manipulate* the parsed grammar, you'll need an abstract syntax tree of same.  You can make most parser generators build a tree, either by using built-in mechanisms or ad hoc code you add.